# Iterar sobre una lista y borrar su contenido Python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando iterar sobre una lista y a la vez ir borrando los elementos de ella si cumple una condición. El problema es que al eliminar un elemento de posición `0`, cuando vuelve a iterar, se salta un elemento, ya que va a la posición `1` (pero me queda sin iterar el elemento que antes era posición `1` que al ser borrado el elemento de pos 0 paso a ser 0). Por lo que no revisa todos los elementos. Intente poner un `while` para que itere mientras la lista tenga un len > 0 pero no me lo toma...Mi objetivo es que la lista quede vacía si es que cumple con la condición. como podría hacer que revise todos los elementos?

```
a=[[],[5,1,2]]
b=[]
for x in range(len(a)):#range(len(a)):
    if len(a[x])>0:
        for i in a[x]:
            if i >x:
                if i not in b:
                    b.append(i)
                    print("no en b",i)
                    a[x].remove(i)
                else:
                    print("si en b",i)
                    a[x].remove(i)
                    if len(a[x])==0:
                        break
print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: Si quieres recorrer una lista eliminando elementos puedes hacerlo recorriendola de fin a principio.

Comment: Realmente, ¿ Cuál es la condición que debe cumplir o no, para borrar el elemento?

Comment: seria si i es mayor a x. i seria el elemento de la sublista. x seria la posicion en la lista principal a. Si el elemento de la sublista a[x], es mayor que x, elminalo. El tema que al eliminarlo, cuando itera sobre el prox elemento queda uno sin revisar ya que se corren las posiciones.

Comment: @Nam como te dijo candidMoe, itera de fin a principio. Otra opción sería iterar en una copia de los datos

Answer (score 0):

Para borrar una elementos de una lista puedes utilizar `while` y `pop`, una estructura como la siguiente:

```py
myList=[1,4,7,4,7,9,3]
myList.reverse() # para no hacerlo al reves, ya que pop devuelve desde el último elemento

while len(myList):
    tempElement=myList.pop()

    print("Elemento de la iteración:", tempElement)

print("Comprueba que está vacía: ", myList)
```

Un *ciclo-while* que se ejecuta mientras la lista tenga elementos poniendo `len(myList)` como condición. Luego dentro del cuerpo debes ir disminuyendo la cantidad de elementos, al mismo tiempo eliminándolos con `myList.pop()`